AWS CDK and Multiple Chalice Apps with CDK-Chalice
My goal is to create an infra stack and create a few lambdas using Chalice that would use the resources on that stack.
There is a tutorial given on https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/aws-chalice-adds-support-for-the-aws-cdk/. I followed the steps and it worked fine. It's using cdk-chalice.
How about adding multiple Chalice Apps on the same infrastructure? Is it possible there?
Any suggestions are also appreciated.
Thanks
